# how to find out combination from following situation

Tags: probability-theory

i have three number
1 2 3  which will always be in this order {123}, i want to find out number of cases can be made,
like {1},{2},{23},{13},{12},{123}{3},{}. but each number has two states like "a" "b", i.e, each one will become different entity,like 2a,2b,3a,3b,1a,
with only exception i.e. 1 will have only one state 1a.

please tel me step wise using formulas, so that i can understand, also, any link will be helpfull.
yours sincerly

Answer (score 0):

For $1$ there are two choices (state "a" or left out). For $2$ and $3$ there are $3$ choices each (state "a" or "b" or left out). So the number of set is:

$2 \times 3 \times 3 = 18$.

In response to your comment, to list them (systematically), here is a SQL procedure that will do it. Even if you're not familiar with SQL, the logic I hope is clear.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PrintSetList
    @MaxNo int,
    @StageBNo int,
    @CurrNo int,
    @CurrStr varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    if @CurrNo = @MaxNo begin -- Reached the last number - time to print
        print '{' + @CurrStr + '   }'
        print '{' + @CurrStr + ' ' + convert(varchar, @CurrNo) + 'a}'
        if @CurrNo >= @StageBNo begin
            print '{' + @CurrStr + ' ' + convert(varchar, @CurrNo) + 'b}'
        end
    end
    else begin
        declare @NextNo int
        declare @NextStr varchar(8000)
        set @NextNo = @CurrNo + 1

        set @NextStr = @CurrStr + '   '
        execute PrintSetList @MaxNo, @StageBNo, @NextNo, @NextStr

        set @NextStr = @CurrStr + ' ' + convert(varchar, @CurrNo) + 'a'
        execute PrintSetList @MaxNo, @StageBNo, @NextNo, @NextStr

        if @CurrNo >= @StageBNo begin
            set @NextStr = @CurrStr + ' ' + convert(varchar, @CurrNo) + 'b'
            execute PrintSetList @MaxNo, @StageBNo, @NextNo, @NextStr
        end
    end
END
```

To run it for you example:

`EXECUTE PrintSetList @MaxNo = 3, @StageBNo = 2, @CurrNo = 1, @CurrStr = ''`

This gave output:

`{         }
{       3a}
{       3b}
{    2a   }
{    2a 3a}
{    2a 3b}
{    2b   }
{    2b 3a}
{    2b 3b}
{ 1a      }
{ 1a    3a}
{ 1a    3b}
{ 1a 2a   }
{ 1a 2a 3a}
{ 1a 2a 3b}
{ 1a 2b   }
{ 1a 2b 3a}
{ 1a 2b 3b}`

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanku, for big numbers it is quite tedious to find the sets, is there any way to find them. yours sincerley

Comment: Do you mean to count how many? Or to list them all? To count is the same idea as for small numbers. E.g. Numbers $1,2,\ldots,50$. Numbers $1-5$ can only have state "a". The remaining $45$ numbers can have states "a" and "b".

The number of combinations is: $2^5 \times 3^{45} = 94538006609626678356576$.

It's just multiplying the number of options available for each of the numbers you have. In this case $2\times2\times2\times2\times2 \times3\times3\times\ldots\times3$.

Comment: to list them all, like {1},{2},{23},{13},{12},{123}{3},{}

Comment: Hi @user3129097 - I've added to my answer to show how listing the combinations can be done.

Answer (score 0):

On stage one, let assume that each number has only one state, and will ask the Q of how many sets we can create. The Answer is simple - each number has 2 options:
1. to be in the set.
 2. no to be in the set.
Thus we end up with $2 \times 2 \times 2$ options.

Now you bring to constraint - with cases to each number than we can follow the same method:
for number $1$ there is $2$ option (as above).
for numbers $2$ and $3$ there are 3 option:
1.$2a$ in the set.
2.$2b$ in the set.
3.$2$ is not in the set. same goes with number 3.
Thus we end up with $2 \times 3 \times 3$ options.

Comment: thanku, for big numbers it is quite tedious to find the sets, is there any way to find them.                                                            yours sincerley